# BundleTransformer.Less isn't processing .less files if variables are out of order

Tags: c#, less, bundletransformer

In the process of updating my nuget packages for BundleTransformer.Less from 1.9.20 to 1.9.143 my application's styles no longer appeared correctly.

I tracked the issue to less not compiling a file because of the order of variable declaration and use.  My understanding of less says you can define a variable after using it, but it is no longer the case for me.  I am able to reproduce with something as simple as

```
html {
    color : @test;
}

@test:green;
```

Which works in online less sandboxes for me.

My app builds and serves up the .less file when requested without error, but the contents of the file is just

```
variable @test is undefined on line 17 in file '/icons.less':
 [16]: html{
 [17]:     color : @test;
       ------------^
 [18]: }
```

What part of compilation would suddenly enforce a requirement about variable orders?

Comment: Seems pretty likely to be a bug introduced in the version gap. If you are working with languages like LESS, you should use proper build tools.

Comment: I'd say that this is not a question for stack overflow - this is a bug you should report to the package creators